# page doesn't display in codeigniter (connect to sql server)

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, view, controller

I start to make web with codeigniter framework and use SQL server as DBMS. But my first page doesn't display View content. What's wrong with this case?
Here are the codes on database.php:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'BRYANWVM1';
$db['default']['username'] = 'sa';
$db['default']['password'] = 'admin%%123';
$db['default']['database'] = 'ej';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
```

here are the codes on controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Ej extends CI_Controller {
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form','url', 'text_helper','date','file'));
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->library();
    $this->load->plugin();
}
function index()
{
    $data=array();
    $this->load->view('electronicjournal/bg_kiri.php',$data);
}
}
```

And here are the codes on Views in electronicjournal folder:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo "".base_url()."index.php/electronicjournal/login" ?>
<table style="border: 1pt ridge #DDDDDD;" bgcolor="#fee3b3" class="widget" width="230">
<tr bgcolor="#fee3b3"><td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFCC66"><h2><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>system/application/views/electronicjoournal/images/login-icon.png" /> Login</h2></td></tr>
<tr bgcolor="#fee3b3"><td width="70" bgcolor="#fee3b3">Username</td><td width="5">:</td>
<td width="130" bgcolor="#fee3b3"><input name="usernameteks" type="text" class="textfield" size="16"/></td></tr>
<tr bgcolor="#fee3b3"><td width="70" bgcolor="#fee3b3">Password</td><td width="5">:</td>
<td width="130" bgcolor="#fee3b3"><input name="passwordteks" type="password" class="textfield" value="" size="16" /></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#fee3b3"><td width="70" bgcolor="#fee3b3"></td>
<td width="5"></td>
<td width="135" bgcolor="#fee3b3"><input type="submit" value="Log In" class="tombol"/><br>
<br></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the url you're accessing? Does the example controller display something? Why do you only print a form and not html/head/body?

Answer (score 0):

problem is in this line :

```
$this->load->view('electronicjournal/bg_kiri.php',$data);
```

you dont need to specify the extension of file. Use this:

```
$this->load->view('electronicjournal/bg_kiri',$data);
```

Comment: The .php extension will be fine as long as the file is a PHP file.